# How to find the first and last date prior to a particular date in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, date

I am a SQL beginner. I have trouble on finding the answer of this question

> For each customer_id who made an order on January 1, 2006, what was their historical (prior to January 1, 2006) first and last order dates?

I've tried to solve it using a subquery. But I don't know how to find the first and last order dates prior to Jan 1.

Columns of table A:

```
customer_id            
order_id              
order_date   
revenue  
product_id
```

Columns of table B:

```
product_id  
category_id
```

```
SELECT customer_id, order_date FROM A
(
     SELECT customer_id FROM A
     WHERE order_date = ‘2006-01-01’
)
WHERE ...
```

Comment: You are looking for `min()` and `max()`

Comment: How do you control the max(order_date) that do not go beyond Jan1,2006? And am I on the right track? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditionals in aggregate functions:

```
SELECT customer_id, MIN(order_date) AS first, MAX(order_date) AS last FROM A 
WHERE customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id FROM A WHERE order_date = ‘2006-01-01’) AND order_date < '2006-01-01'
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

Comment: I see what it does. It took me a while. But I still cannot figure out how to make sure out of those order_date that an order was made on Jan 1,2006.
Like, if that customer made an order on Jan 1, 2006, then execute the conditionals in aggregate functions that you suggested.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the condition for the users. I've added a subquery that takes that into account.

Answer (score 0):

There are two subqueries actually. First for "*For each customer_id who made an order on January 1, 2006*" and second for "*their historical (prior to January 1, 2006) first and last order dates*"

So, first:

```
select customer_id from A where order_date = '2006-01-01';
```

and second:

```
select customer_id, min(order_date) as first_date, max(order_date) as last_date
from A
where order_date < '2006-01-01' group by customer_id;
```

Finally you need to get only those customers from second subquery who exists in the first one:

```
select customer_id, min(order_date) as first_date, max(order_date) as last_date
from A as t1
where 
    order_date < '2006-01-01' and
    customer_id in (
        select customer_id from A where order_date = '2006-01-01')
group by customer_id;
```

or, could be more efficient:

```
select customer_id, min(order_date) as first_date, max(order_date) as last_date
from A as t1
where 
    order_date < '2006-01-01' and
    exists (
        select 1 from A as t2
        where t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id and t2.order_date = '2006-01-01')
group by customer_id;
```